# Не удается изменить текст <label> с помощью textContent js

Tags: javascript, html

Пытаюсь менять форму входа при разных выбранных радио-кнопках.

```css
let findSelected=()=> {
  let selected=document.querySelector("input[name='check']:checked").value;
  console.log(selected);
  if (selected==="user") {
    document.querySelector(".userLabel").textContent="Username";
  }
  if (selected==="guest") {
    document.querySelector(".userLabel").textContent="Pseudonym";
  }
}

;
```

```html
<form action="submit" class="login-form">
    <label for="username-input" class="userLabel">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-input" id="username-input" required />
    <label for="password-input" class="passwordLabel">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-input" id="password-input" required />
    <div class="radioContainer">
        <div>
            <label class="radioLabel">
                <input type="radio" name="check" value="user" class="radio" checked />
                <span class="fake"></span>
                <span>User</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label class="radioLabel">
                <input type="radio" name="check" value="guest" class="radio" />
                <span class="fake"></span>
                <span>Guest</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Log in" class="form-button" />
    <p>Not registered yet?:(</p>
    <div class="sign"><span>Sign in!</span></div>
</form>
```

При проверке, в консоль выводятся строки "user" и "guest", но появляется ошибка (textContent принимает null)

Comment: Если добавить недостающий кусок кода, отвечающий за отслеживание изменений состояния радио-кнопок и вызова функции `findSelected()`, то [всё работает без ошибок](https://jsfiddle.net/3qdmaLgh/). Перепроверьте селектор `<label>`.